# AWS Load Balancer wont work AT ALL, despite all health checks working

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have an EC2 instance set up that clearly works when accessing the IP
When I add a load balancer, and route HTTP/HTTPS to the target, it says all health checks are good. It registers my instance as running.

But when I try and access the LB, it times out. There are no errors. No logs. Nothing. I'm using default security groups for everything.

Comment: Did you configure private subnets for the load balancer? You need to specify public subnets.

Comment: You still have to configure input ports on your security group you know

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem.
The default security group in AWS Load balancer wizard does not work AT ALL. I had to manually add HTTP & HTTP entries. I think its pretty dumb that the defaults don't work for such a basic use case.